# Does going in and out php tags slows down overall execution process?

Tags: php

Does going in and out php tags slows down overall execution process ?

i mean writing several `<?php ?>` in the script, when i can write only one to embrace the whole code.

Comment: It only really matters if you have *a lot* of them. Do whatever makes your code easier to maintain.

Comment: Thank you both , and yes it answered my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I honestly don't know. So the only way to find out is to create a small benchmark script.

I have created a benchmark script before so I modified my code to suit your question :

```
<?php
function loadtime_start(){
    $time = microtime();
    $time = explode(' ', $time);
    $time = $time[1] + $time[0];
    $start = $time;

    return($start);
}
function loadtime_end($start){
    $time = microtime();
    $time = explode(' ', $time);
    $time = $time[1] + $time[0];
    $finish = $time;
    $total_time = round(($finish - $start), 4);

    return($total_time);
}




$start = loadtime_start();

for($i = 0; $i<100000; $i++){
    ?>
    We have something I guess bro!<br />
    <?php
}

$inout_time = loadtime_end($start);
$start = loadtime_start();
for($i = 0; $i<100000; $i++){
    echo 'We have something I guess bro!<br />';
}
$php_echo_time = loadtime_end($start);



echo 'Time for in / out : '.$inout_time.PHP_EOL.'Time for PHP echo :'.$php_echo_time;
```

Simply run this script and you'll know the result.

My results are :

**Time for in / out : 0.1009 Time for PHP echo :0.1705**

Comment: So its a very small time , almost negligible, and it wont affect or cause performance issues with modern CPUs or Hardware

Comment: Well you got your answer ;-)